# Subview is displaying outside of its superview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

In my iPad application, I have a `UIView` object named "myView" whose frame is (0, 0, 600, 500). Now I want to add a `UIImageView` in this myview, so here is my code for doing this:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-100, 0,100, 200)];
[myImageView setImage:UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
[myView addSubView:myImageView];
[myImageView release];
```

So according to this code myImageView should not be displayed as its x-coordinate is "-100" and width is "100". But it is displaying out of myView at left side.

Can anyone please help to resolve this problem?

Comment: It might help you: [Click this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016354/subview-displaying-outside-the-bounds-of-the-parent-uiview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIView`'s `clipsToBounds` property, which is off by default.