# Subview displaying outside the bounds of the parent UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIView that contain another subview. The subview's frame is outside of the bounds of the super view. But the entire subview is visible in when I run the application. 
Example:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                          +
+       Super view         +
+                          +
+                          +
+     --------------------------                    
+     -  Subview           +   -                     
+     -                    +   -                     
+     --------------------------                    
+                          +
+                          +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Should be:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                          +
+       Super view         +
+                          +
+                          +
+     ---------------------+                  
+     -  Subview           +                       
+     -                    +                     
+     ---------------------+                   
+                          +
+                          +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Any idea?

Comment: Beautifully illustrated

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're setting up your views in code, set the `clipsToBounds` property of the superview to `YES`.

If you're setting up your views in a nib, turn **on** the “Clip Subviews” checkbox on the superview.  It's off by default, as in this screenshot:

[image: Clip Subviews checkbox]

Comment: I want subview to out of frame, But its not visible(outer part of subview)

Comment: @sivakrishna, I want to do the same thing, did you achieved that by this time?

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically

**`[YourSuperview setClipsToBounds:YES]`**